# getpid(), getppid() for a whole program?

Tags: c

I have search around but have been unable to find what I was looking for. I know that getpid() returns the process ID of the calling process and getppid() returns the process ID of the parent of the calling process. But is there a function that can get the process ID of a program? Or is that what one of the two above actually do?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: From the title it looks like you confuse [`process`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) with [`thread`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there a function that can get the process ID of a program?

This quote from Wikipedia's definition of a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_process) , would answer your above question..

> In computing, a process is an instance of a computer program that is
>   being executed. It contains the program code and its current activity.

Answer (score 4):

A program does not have a `PID`. `PID` means process ID. A process is a running instance of a 
program. So only when the program is executed it gets a `PID`.

Answer (score 3):

That **is** what getpid() does. A process is a running instance of a program.

Comment: A question is never stupid. As @coredump said, a process is a running instance of a program. I should have been more precise.